# Why does Harvest utilise https://COMPANYNAME.harvestapp.com

Tags: web-services

I am looking into utilizing Harvest for a time tracking and invoice solution and was hoping someone would be able to shed some light as to why they use the means of logging into their account with the following format 'https://COMPANYNAME.harvestapp.com', and not just logging straight in through their site.

Many Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is because of ability to

1. rebrand landing page for login
2. allow to login simultaniously in multiple instances at the same time.
3. simplier cdn managment.

and so on - benefits from using unique domains.